# Java ,GUI window builder

Tags: eclipse, user-interface, jframe, window, builder

[image: 1]

how can return my class to defualt setting 
I need to see the  source /desgin

please help 
Thanks

Comment: I create Jframe class and after time the source /desgin hide.                    how can I return to default viwe

Answer (score 0):

I think i have a fix for you.
Click New -> Other -> SWT/JFace Java Project
then right click on source-> New -> Other -> Application Window -> paste your code in it.
[Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Fqee.png)

Comment: I find the solution   >>>>>>>>     right click -> open with ->                   window builder